# Show vertical and horizontal navbar once logged in

Tags: c#, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, single-page-application

I was wondering if there was a way I could show a vertical and horizontal navbar once the user has been authenticated.

I have this code working for the horizontal navbar:

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" data-ng-controller="indexController">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand">
        <img src="/images/AltheaLogo.png" alt="AltheaDx" style="margin-top: -13px; background-color: #E0E0E0 ">
      </a>
      <button class="btn btn-success navbar-toggle" data-ng-click="navbarExpanded = !navbarExpanded">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" data-collapse="!navbarExpanded">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <!-- ReSharper disable once Html.IdNotResolved -->
        <li data-ng-hide="!authentication.isAuth"><a href="#/dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
        <!-- ReSharper disable once Html.IdNotResolved -->
        <li data-ng-hide="!authentication.isAuth"><a href="#/physicians">Physicians</a></li>
        <!-- ReSharper disable once Html.IdNotResolved -->
        <li data-ng-hide="!authentication.isAuth"><a href="#/patients">Patients</a></li>
        <!-- ReSharper disable once Html.IdNotResolved -->
        <li data-ng-hide="!authentication.isAuth"><a href="#/orders">Order Products</a></li>
        <!-- ReSharper disable once Html.IdNotResolved -->
        <li data-ng-hide="!authentication.isAuth"><a href="#/users">Users</a></li>
        <li data-ng-hide="!authentication.isAuth"><a href="#">Loged in as: {{authentication.userName}}</a></li>
        <li data-ng-hide="!authentication.isAuth"><a href="" data-ng-click="logOut()">Logout</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The purpose of the vertical navbar is to allow the user to view different pages.  for instance, if they are looking at a list of Physicians, the vertical menu would allow them to view more details of the physician or to add a physician.  Or is this a bad design?  If so what is a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not consider implementing the vertical nav bar as a directive and hosting it in a column in the main layout? Inside the vertical nav bar directive, you can use other directives to cater for specific functions.

Once you have the column, you can use ng-hide or ng-if to display it only when the user is logged in

```
<div class='col-md-2' data-ng-show='authentication.isAuth'}>
  <vertical-nav>
    <previous-bookings></previous-bookings>
    <doctor-info></doctor-info>
  </vertical-nav>
</div>
```